# How to cast array elements within UNNEST statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a `REPEATED` column of type `ARRAY[STRING]` in BigQuery, and I want to create a filter on it that does this :

```
SELECT campaign,
       event_list
FROM `adobe_analytics.raw_data_20200*`
WHERE campaign IS NOT NULL
AND "1" IN UNNEST(split(event_list,","))
```

Except I don't want to look for `"1"`, I want to convert the column `event_list` into `integer_event_list` of type `ARRAY[INT]` and then have a clause like this `WHERE 1 IN UNNEST(integer_event_list)`. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT campaign, event_list
FROM `adobe_analytics.raw_data_20200*`
WHERE campaign IS NOT NULL
AND 1 IN (SELECT CAST(e AS INT64) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(event_list,",")) e)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.

It is not obvious to me how casting the `ARRAY<String>` `e` into an `INT64` makes it into an `ARRAY<INT64>`. Is that some kind of syntactic sugar where `INT64` is the conversion "applied" to each element of the original array? Could you provide an additional explanation?

Comment: `select ... from ...` is an unnested array of resulted rows - this is just a nature of select's output - hope this explain you the underlying 'magic'